# MSMQ queue is readable from a workgroup client but not available for read from inside of the domain

Tags: msmq, windows-server-2008-r2

There's a number of questions discussing a situation when a remote private MSMQ queue is writable but not readable. In my situation the strange thing is that queues are available both for read and write operations from clients that are outside of the domain where MSMQ cluster is located (those clients are in workgroup - not part of any domain) but for clients that are members of the same domain it is not possible to open a queue for reading (writing does work).

Here is an error message obtained when trying to open a queue for reading:

```
  "<COMObject MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo>", line 3, in Open   pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'MSMQQueueInfo','Generic error code. ', None, 0, -1072824319), None)
```

This error message is for `pywin32`. The same error code `2147352567` is returned from `.NET` application.

The queues are in MS cluster consisting of 2 Windows servers (2008 R2). All clients also have Windows Server 2008 R2 OS. MSMQ cluster instance has `AllowNonauthenticatedRPC` and `NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient` set to `1` in registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Clustered QMs\MSMQ$MSMQ Service\Parameters\security`). The queues have full access granted to `Everyone` and `ANONYMOUS LOGON`. Everything had been working perfectly until some time before a cluster disk hosting the queues was recreated. I suspect that it might be something related to caching but not sure what further troubleshooting steps to take.

Update: It is now possible to open a queue for reading from within the domain. No settings were changed. In the process of troubleshooting the whole MSMQ cluster service was deleted and created from scratch but it didn't start working right after that but rather several hours after that. It was either some kind of a glitch or is related to some security settings changes that I don't know about.

Comment: How are you addressing the private queue?

Comment: Writing and reading use different protocols (MSMQ and RPC respectively) so you need to troubleshoot the RPC side of things. You have the two registry values OK, as mentioned in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic/. Also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2009/05/17/failing-to-read-from-remote-msmq-queues/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2008/07/10/getting-msmq-messages-out-of-windows-server-2008-remotely/.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell, I'm addressing the private queue with the following format: `"direct=os:computer_name\\private$\\queue_name"`

Comment: It started working again after some time without any settings changed. This was probably a glitch.

Comment: Weird. Any difference in physical location between a workgroup client and a domain client?

Comment: @JohnBreakwell, no, there are not differences in physical location. I agree, it looks weird.